# Script tag not running properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I think it's best to start by showing the portion of code in question:

```
<script>
    alert("check 1");
</script>

<script>
    alert("check 2");
    $("#exams").change(function(){
        alert("prechanged");
        var exam = $("#exams").val();
        alert("changed");
        alert("<%= examBoard.length %>");
        <% for(var i=0;i<examBoard.length;i++){ %>
            alert("got this far");
            if(<%= examBoard[i].name %> == exam){
                alert("got quite far");
                <% for(var t=0;t<examBoard[i].modules.length;t++){ %>
                    $("#modules").append("<option value='<%= examBoard[i].modules[t].name %>'><%= examBoard[i].modules[t].name %></option>");
                <% } %>
                <% break; %>
            }
        <% } %>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').material_select();
        });
    });

</script>
```

This code then produces this output when run (this is of course cropped down just to show the `alert` box):

[image]

The issue as described in the title being it never shows the `check 2` `alert` box nor any of the other `alert` boxes within the 2nd `script` tag.

I have not provided full context for the reason that I beleive it would merely drastically affect readability and provide nothing of use, but just in case I'm wrong here is a Hastebin link to the full code (https://hastebin.com/atanusagij.xml).

Should be noted this is the error that shows in the console after clicking ok to the `check 1` alert box, which is rather odd considering I must have checked the syntax in my code ten times by now and found no issues:

[image]
[image]

I don't beleive an explanation of what it accomplishes is even necessary but I shall provide one regardless just in case. Effectively each value in the `select` html element with id `exams` refers to an item in the database and each of these items has modules embedded in them. So when the user selects an exam from the first `select` the program then changes the options in the `select` with id `modules` to match the modules embedded in the exam item in the database.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` inside `click` function is wrong. and your code will produce error(check your browser console regarding this)

Comment: I don't see a reason why "check 2" `alert` is not being shown. The `alert()` is a blocking call. This means that it will block the execution of script until "OK" is clicked. Did you click the OK button on "check 1" `alert`?

Comment: @Kashif Yes.1234

Comment: What if you put everything in a single script tag? Does it work then?

Comment: @KillerDeath No.

Comment: Errors in console?

Comment: Can you look into the generated HTML code and share with us how the two `<script>` tags are in the HTML. For this, load this page in browser (by serving it from a web server e.g. localhost) and view page source.

Comment: "Should be noted this is the error that shows in the console: " ....then you explicitly show us the exact issue that is causing that whole script tag contents to crap the bed......

Comment: @TravisActon Except you can clearly see the syntax in the actual code is not incorrect. If you bring the sassy I shall reply sassy.

Comment: I can clearly see that you didn't close your If statement when checking if a === exam which is causing it to process the end of your change event as the end of the if and freaking out that it finds a ) trailing it. But who knows what else is screwed before or after since this is only a small partial image you've shown. Not meaning to be "sassy" but com'on man, it's right there and its telling you it's right there.

Comment: @TravisActon I fixed the issue by the way, if your interested check my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer here was a little contrived and unfortunately does actually make the code less efficient but when looking in the 2nd `script` tag the `<% break; %>` meant that the code would never reach the closing bracket of the if statement, which resulted in the error seen. The simple solution is removing the `<% break; %>` although it is quite possible there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

What event is the DOM listening to before the function? You need to paste the html code for more clarity. You might also want to use a single script tag to run all your JS code.

Comment: Using a single 'script' tag seems to makes no difference, the only reason I use multiple in this case is because it would seem the issue is not simply with the 'script' tag here. You can also check out the Hastebin link for full context.